# Rails 4 how to calculate sum for dynamic queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sum

Having a challenge to calculate sum for dynamically built request.

I'm using each method to get value for each element and it work seamless.

```
 <% params[:car].map{|n| n.first}.each do |p|%>
   <%= @salon.price.send("price_" + p) %>
 <% end %>
```

But then I'm trying to get sum for the same dynamically ("price_" + p) built queries it's failing.

```
<%= @salon.price.where("price_" + params[:car].map{|n| n.first}.to_s).all %>
```

Tried multiple solutions and no luck

Comment: You want some of params[:car].each{|n| n.first} this please explain more

Comment: At the very least, could you display what `params[:car]` value is? Is it an object? A hash?

Comment: I want to calculate sum from price table for selected params.
db looks like:  id / price_0 /price_1 , so I'm trying to get sum for (price_0 + price_1)

Comment: You have `where` but haven't given it an actual `where`-like clause do you mean `@salon.price.sum()` instead? Otherwise what are you trying to filter on (where is for filtering, sum is for summation).

Comment: @Finks it is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `where` but haven't given it an actual where-like clause do you mean `@salon.price.sum()` instead? Otherwise what are you trying to filter on (`where` is for filtering, `sum` is for summation).

So what you seem to want to do is:

- for all the prices for a given salon
- sum up the columns `price_0..price_n`

right?

Now it'd be easy to construct a query to sum up the values for a *single* column

For that you'd try something like this:

```
<%= @salon.price.sum("price_0") %>
```

This uses the Rails `sum` method that works on any Active Record association.

And if you had a *single* price object and wanted to sum up all the `price_X` columns for that single price, you'd use something like this:

```
<%= params[:car].map{|n| price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum %>
```

This turns the numbers in `params[:car]` into an array of the column-values for the given price-object... then sums them at the end using the `sum` method that comes from the `Array` class (AKA `Array#sum`)

so to combine those two, you'd probably need something like this:

```
<%= @salon.prices.all.sum{|price| params[:car].map{|n| price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum } %>
```

Yes, that's a block inside a block.

Now it's possible that the Active Record version of `sum` can interfere with `Array#sum` and not like the above (which looks more like how you'd do the `Array#sum`). Rails' `sum` expects you to pass it the name of a single column like in the first example, rather than a block, like in the second example. So sometimes you then need to use `map` (which turns your set of values into an array) and then you can use `Array#sum` at the end like this:

```
<%= @salon.prices.all.map{|price| params[:car].map{|n| price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum }.sum %>
```

So that's a block (whose values are summed) inside another block (whose values are summed)

EDIT:
after discussion it seems you only have a single `price` record... and multiple columns on that single record... this changes things and makes them much simpler. You can just use this:

```
<%= params[:car].map{|n| @salon.price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum %>
```

Comment: <%= @salon.price.map{|price| params[:car].map{|n| price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum }.sum %>
for some reason it is not able to map values 
undefined method `map' for #<Price:0x007fb33b3033b0>

Comment: Fair enough, you may need to use `all` before using map... which will turn it into an Association (which will act like an array). I'm assuming you have more than one price per salon (eg it's a `has_many`)? you might want to call that association `prices` instead of `price` so it makes sense.

Comment: I have belongs_to Association Salon and price 
<%= @salon.price.all.map{|price| params[:car].map{|n| price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum }.sum %>  also failing for  - undefined method `all'

Comment: Right... so belongs-to means there is just a single `price`, not many `prices`... which makes things very different. You can just use my second example instead of needing the third/fourth

Comment: in second solution <%= params[:car].map{|n| @salon.price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s) }.sum %> seems start working only one issue sum not calculated properly, I have 30 + 25  and it showing sum as = 3025 instead of 55

Comment: <%= params[:car].map{|n| @salon.price.send("price_" + n.first.to_s).to_i}.sum %>  I switched response to integer and seems works .. Thanks!!!  Awesome answer!

Comment: ha - looks like you need them to be integers and not strings then :) Why are your `price_x` value-columns set as strings?

Comment: No idea :) It was done before me, so I have to fix that one as well

Answer (score 0):

You use **sum** method for the array

```
  sum = params[:car].map{|n| n.first}.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to get the sum of columns named `price_n` in the `Price` table where `n` is the value of `params[:car].map(:&first)`. So I think the simple solution is:

```
<% params[:car].map(&first).each do |n| %>
  <% sum += @salon.price.send("price_#{n.to_s") %>
<% end %>

<%= sum %>
```

But seeing the logic in the view is not a rails best practice, so it's better if we move the entire logic in your helper method. So in the view, just display this code:

```
<%= total_of_all_prices(params[:car], @salon.price) %>
```

Then in your helper method add this method

```
def total_of_all_prices(car_params, price_object)
  sum = 0

  car_params.map(&:first).each do |n|
    sum += price_object.send("price_#{n.to_s}")
  end

  sum
end
```

Comment: getting  'String can't be coerced into Fixnum' with helper solution

Comment: Then convert the `n` to a string by adding a `to_s` method. I have edited it.